# What is the name of this camera work used in the opening shot of After Hours?

Tags: film-techniques, cinematography, after-hours

What is the name of the camera technique used for the dynamic opening shot of Martin Scorsese's *After Hours*?

Comment: Looks like a combined Zoom & Pan.

Comment: It's one of his signature moves: the fast dolly in with a little bit of zoom (and/or pan) to catch the moment. He started doing it in *Mean Streets* and has continued doing it through *The Wolf of Wall Street*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Dolly shot](http://www.mediacollege.com/video/shots/dolly.html), or tracking shot. Some use both terms interchangeably, while others define tracking shot as a side-to-side motion and dolly shot as an in-out motion. In this case, the motion is diagonal, so it would be a diagonal dolly shot (or diagonal tracking shot).